# Numpy commands not working as they did 3 weeks ago

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder

I need some help/advice. First off, I am using Python 2.7.14 and I use it through the Spyder 3.2.6 interface. I have never utilized python 3. I have a 64 bit Windows 10 OS and have extremely limited ability to update things due to workplace network restrictions. So nothing should have been updated automatically except windows-based things.

I use a script to generate plots from data on my computer. It was working perfectly 3 weeks ago when I used it last. Here is a portion of it:

```
import numpy as np
def map_track(): 
    A1=loadtxt("C:\data\island.shape", usecols=(0,1))
```

Resulting in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-af497edda909>", line 1, in <module>
    A1=loadtxt("C:\data\island.shape", usecols=(0,1))

NameError: name 'loadtxt' is not defined
```

I have found that using np.loadtxt will eliminate the error, but I have a lot of different python code that utilize numpy commands and it would be tedious to have to manually add 'np.' at the beginning of each instance. I use many more commands from numpy including percentile and isnan, which both generated the same error that is "fixed" by adding np. before them.

I am not overly experienced in checking, installing, uninstalling, etc. packages and I am at a loss as to what I am supposed to look for in attempting to fix this. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: this is properly due to an import statement as follows `from numpy import *`

Comment: How are those commands supposed to work without adding `np` as prefix? For numpy commands to work, you need to add the abbreviation that you define.

Comment: Correct - or if you need nothing else `from numpy import loadtxt`...

Comment: I'm not sure how they did work before, but they did. I have been using numpy commands for 4-5 years (merely having import numpy as np at the beginning of python code file) without needing to explicitly use np.  @sgDysregulation, thank you for that fix and all running okay once more.

Comment: It looks like spyder was automagically importing parts of numpy for you.  Something must have updated or caused that to change, so I'd start by checking what configuration spyder has and how it could have been changed.

Comment: The `pylab` mode for `ipython` loads numpy as both `*` and `np`.  To force myself to be consistent when answering SO questions, I've turned off the `*` load (in the config file).